# Network problem with two cards in Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: networking, server

I have a network problem with Ubuntu 14.04 Server when I use two LAN cards. look

When I want to make `static ip` in first network name is `p2p1/`, second is `p4p1`, this how the PC indicates them, not `eth0`.

I use this config in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# The primary network interface
auto p2p1

iface p2p1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.1
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8


# The secondary network interface
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.1
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 4.4.4.4
```

Net goes off, not working even to try to `ping google` or `apt-get update` fails too. Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: You have two different gateways defined - your system will get these two confused as to the proper 'default route' to the Internet or Networks.  You'd have to pick *one* as the gateway, and that would be the default route.  Otherwise, it's a *massively* complex setup to get everything working proper with multiple interfaces and gateway routes.  (That is, define the gateway for one, but not the second, if they ultimately go out to the same Internet source, and pick which is the 'default route')

Comment: please can you correct to me this config

Comment: i need to use 192.168.1.2 as innetwork and 192.168.0.2 as out to give to friends

Comment: Without knowing more details of your network, not really.   Do both `192.168.1.*` and `192.168.0.*`both go out over the same Internet provider connection, or separate ones?  If they go through the same, then pick which one you want to have the default 'internet' route to, if they both go through different ISPs, then we'll have to do much more complex configurations.

Comment: look plz mate this one 192.168.1.2 commes from router of my provider / while this one is second lan of my pc 192.168.0.2 i use to give to friends in other rooms sothat it is like outside net only and it is connected with nano loco to send them with defirent not same like my provider

Comment: this one is with same network 192.168.1.2 it goes in the pc ubuntu server and the second lan 192.168.0.2 is out not from my provider

Comment: any idea please how to config this

Comment: i found the solution thanx